# GWT, Tomcat, 2 modules, JRebel: DevMode looks for nocache.js in wrong location and shows 404 not found

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jrebel, gwt-dev-mode

I'll ask my questions first and then go into details:

1. What function `hosted.html` file plays in `DevMode` and why it is requested from page like `hosted.html?<module-name>` and how can I control/configure what is returned by that request? **If anyone answers this question, I'll upvote & accept the answer** since I've already found answers to 2nd and 3rd questions myself and they doesn't seem to be related to my problem.
2. Are there any ways of triggering GWT cache refresh instead of plain browser `Ctrl-F5`? In each module I've seen generated during compilation `clear.cache.gif` file - does it have any relation to GWT cache? **already answered by myself and doesn't seem to be of much help in this situation**
3. Did I correctly specified `DevMode`s `-war` path (see below)? Should I instead specify absolute path to `src/main/webapp` folder? **already answered by myself and doesn't seem to be of much help in this situation**
4. What is the problem with my setup and why I'm having problem described below? (**optional to answer, but if answered correctly - I'll upvote & accept the answer right away :)**)

**EDIT - details related to 1st question**

So there are 2 GWT modules: `login` and `dashboard` in my webapp. The problem is that in `DevMode` page `login.html` containing only `login` module **always** loads normally, making following request

```
GET http://localhost:8080/login/hosted.html?login                200 OK
```

Which returns standard `hosted.html` page which is generated by GWT compiler and put into each module's folder.

**But** somewhy `dashboard.html` page containing only `dashboard` module doesn't load normally making following request:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/dashboard/hosted.html?dashboard        304 Not Modified

Cache-Control:private
Date:Tue, 17 Dec 2013 13:07:40 GMT
ETag:W/"11781-1367504122000"
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 03:00:00 EET
Last-Modified:Thu, 02 May 2013 14:15:22 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Which **surprisingly** returns `login.html` page as a result and not standard `hosted.html` file which I would expect. Please note that this happened quite rarely during the last half a year and was solved by pressing Ctrl-F5 multiple times. But since yesterday, this happens always.

Continuing to search, who or what makes request to `hosted.html?dashboard` and who is responding to it with such strange response.

**EDIT #2 - details related to 1st question**
It was found out that the problem is on the server side - somewhy response to second request (mentioned above) has status code `304 Not Modified`. While debugging Catalina code it was found out that the problem is with `org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.fileservlet.FileServlet` class which in the end serves the file. This class is from `JRebel` (version 5.2.2) which is launched with Tomcat using `-javaagent` option. If I remove `-javaagent` option and launch Tomcat without `JRebel` everything works fine and correct file is served. Will try to dig deeper and find out the problem in JRebel's class.

**EDIT #3 - details related to 1st question**

After upgrading to `JRebel-5.4.2` the error still persists.
Started topic on `Zeroturnaround` forum:
http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/gwt-devmode-tomcat-7-0-39-possible-fileservlet-bug/

**Detailed description of my problem** (nothing very interesting - just details :)):

I'm having a problem with `Devmode` of webapp running 2 modules called `login` and `dashboard`. Webapp is being deployed locally to standard tomcat installation and has directory structure like the following:

```
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/login.html
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/login/
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/login/<single gwt.rpc file>
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/login/<multiple .cache.html files>
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/login/gwt/<standard files>
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/login/clear.cache.gif
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/login/login.nocache.js
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/login/hosted.html

<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/dashboard.html
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/dashboard/
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/dashboard/<two .gwt.rpc files>
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/dashboard/<multiple .cache.html, .cache.png, etc files>
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/dashboard/gwt/<standard files>
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/dashboard/clear.cache.gif
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/dashboard/dashboard.nocache.js
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/dashboard/hosted.html
<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/dashboard/<other css and image resources used by page>

<tomcat_folder>/webapps/ROOT/<other files of webapp>
```

Now, `login.html` contains reference to `login.nocache.js` file like the following:

```
    <script src="login/login.nocache.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

`dashboard.html` contains reference to `dashboard.nocache.js` file respectively:

```
    <script src="dashboard/dashboard.nocache.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

I launch the `DevMode` from `Eclipse` with the following parameters:

```
-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" 
-startupUrl http://localhost:8080/login.html -logLevel INFO 
-noserver -war <absolute-path-to-tomcat-folder>/webapps/ROOT 
-codeServerPort 9997 
org.yura.cases.DashboardModule org.yura.cases.LoginModule
```

Now, I'm working with such setup for already half a year now and everything was working fine i.e. it works flawlessly not in `DevMode` and, say, 95% of time I was successfully working with `DevMode` - debugging code, changing it in Eclipse etc.

But, the problem is (and was in the past) that, from time to time, when I open

```
http://localhost:8080/dashboard.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

page is blank and I see following error in browsers console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/dashboard/login/login.nocache.js/ 404 (Not Found)  hosted.html:10
```

When I go to `hosted.html:10` file which is loaded during page load I see that this file is loaded from following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/dashboard/hosted.html?dashboard
```

and the returned HTML file indeed contains wrong path to `login.nocache.js`:

```
<script src="login/login.nocache.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

(path is wrong because `login/login.nocache.js' is relative path and it resolves to`dashboard/login/login.nocache.js`)

Till today, I bypassed this problem by simply holding `Ctrl-F5` for several seconds to reload page and clear browser cache and eventually page loaded normally in `DevMode`. However, today, no matter how long I press `Ctrl-F5` the error persists. That's why I decided to finally solve this problem once and for all.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answers to my 2nd and 3rd question, though they doesn't seem to be of much help with my problem. Anyway, sharing them here:

> Question 2. Are there any ways of triggering GWT cache refresh instead of plain browser Ctrl-F5? In each module I've seen generated during compilation
>   clear.cache.gif file - does it have any relation to GWT cache?

As per http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#launching_a_browser :

> You do not need to restart development mode after modifying your source code. Instead, with Development Mode still running, edit client code or resources, save your changes, then refresh the page in your browser.

And as per [GWT project directory creation by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804192/gwt-project-directory-creation-by-hand) :

> clear.cache.gif is a 1x1 cacheable image used to have a placeholder for the  tag. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/ImageBundleDesign ("Clipping constructor for Image")

So it turns out that in my case, pressing F5 or Ctrl-F5 should totally do the trick and there are no other means of "refreshing" GWT cache at least well-declared to the public.

> Question 3. Did I correctly specified DevModes -war path (see below)? Should I instead specify absolute path to src/main/webapp folder?

Yes, as per [Using my own server in development mode instead of GWT's built-in Jetty instance](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s) tutorial, I've specified `-war` option correctly.

**EDIT - found answer to 4th question (solution to my problem)**
Ok, so it turned out that the bug was in `org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.fileservlet.FileServlet` class, which was incorrectly handling `ETag` header in rare cases. That's why it served `login.html` content which was returned previously by Tomcat as result of non-authenticated access to protected `/dashboard/hosted.html?dashboard` resource (weird but standard behaviour of Tomcat). Bugfix of JRebel should appear in today's nightly build and I'm 99% sure it will work :)

For details please refer to this discussion: http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/gwt-devmode-tomcat-7-0-39-possible-fileservlet-bug/#post-39379

Really hope this helps someone else :)